# Checking if connection has been established-jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to extract some information from a website. Here's the code for that.

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(s_url); //s_url has been initialized to contain the url
conn.timeout(300000); //5 minutes
Document doc = conn.get();
//some code
```

The connection seems to take considerable amount of time, about 8-10s. I am trying to display something like

```
Connecting...
```

with the dots increasing while the connection is being established. Is there any way to check if the connection has been established with jsoup? If not, is it possible to do it in any other way in Java?

Comment: Probably the first time my question has gone unanswered. Anyone?

Comment: `Jsoup.connect(path).execute()` returns a Response. If it's not null you have connected. Look through the Jsoup API and you'll find useful methods.

Comment: 5 minutes won't happen. You can't increase the connection timeout beyond the platform default of about a minute. You can only shorten it. The Javadoc is mistaken on this point.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use threads. Spawn a thread that will connect to a server, and in a main thread wait for it to finish, while printing dots:

```
        Thread t = new Thread(

           new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Connecting");
                try{
                     loginForm = Jsoup.connect(s_url).execute();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        }


        );
        t.start();
        while(t.isAlive()){
            Thread.sleep(1000); //1 second
            System.out.print(".");
        }
```